# Adding indexes to a postgres table after it is created and and having partitions

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table named: `services`, and it has columns called `id, mac_addr, dns_name, hash`, and it is partitioned based on `mac_addr`, so the partition tables names look like: `services_3eeeea123e3` and so on. And there are around `20K partition` based on `mac_addrs`

Q1: there was no index created when the tables were created. so now, when I am trying to add an index `CREATE INDEX idx_services_id on services (id)`, it throws an `error ERROR:  cannot create an index on partitioned table "services"`
But I am able to add indexes to individual partitioned tables `CREATE INDEX idx_services_3eeeea123e3 on services_3eeeea123e3 (id)`.
So do I have to create an index on each partition table now? Is there a way to create an index on the base table(services) itself, which will automatically create an index on each partition table?

Q2: When I run a select query, it is fast when I use the direct partition table; however, using the base table is very slow. Any idea what could be the reason.
Fast: `SELECT id, dns_name, hash from services_3eeeea123e3 where id='123232'`
very slow: `SELECT id,dns_name, hash from services where mac_addr='3eeeea123e3' and id='123232'`

Comment: Don't use PostgreSQL v10 when using partitioning. Don't use v10 at all. For the second question, we would need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: I agree with Laurenz: if you really need partitioning, upgrade to Postgres 14 - **especially** if you have so many partitions. Then both your problems will go away (#1 definitely and #2 most probably)

Comment: Why do you need so many partitions? A single partition can easily handle hundreds of millions records.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, The total data we have is around 4TB, and I recall correctly that the number of records was a few quadrillions.

Comment: @Tanuj: 4TB in 20.000 partitions means that you have just a 200MB of data in each partition. That’s almost nothing. We usually try to keep a 50GB in a partition, that works good for our system. That would also massively reduce your number of partitions, just a few hundred.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankHeikens, for responding. Data in each table is not evenly distributed, so we can't say  200MB in each partition. Some partition tables have >20GB of data, and some have very few MB. as it is partitioned by mac address, and some of the mac addr are very noisy and create enormous data sets.